# Canvas image not scrolling seamlessly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

Good day,

I've been trying a lot to seamlessly repeat the canvas image but I've failed to do so inside the canvas,

The problem seems to be inside this function's definition:
RepositionImage()

It creates a gap between the two images once it re-positions the image to the canvas.

Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
public class ImageMove:MonoBehaviour
{
    private BoxCollider2D imageCollider;
    private float imageHorizontalLength;
    [SerializeField]
    private float scrollSpeed;
    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(-scrollSpeed, 0);
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        imageCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        imageHorizontalLength = imageCollider.size.x;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (GetComponent<RectTransform>().offsetMin.x < -imageHorizontalLength)
        {
            rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            RepositionImage();
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(-scrollSpeed, 0);
        }
    }

    void RepositionImage()
    {
        Vector2 offset = new Vector2(imageHorizontalLength, 0);
        GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = (Vector2)transform.position + offset;
    }
}
```

[View Gap Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzxpr.png)

Comment: You're using the width of the box collider, does it line up perfectly with the image?  Have you tried to use the width of the transform attached to whichever object owns the `Image` component?

Comment: Side note: get rid of the lines `rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;` and `rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(-scrollSpeed, 0);` surrounding `RepositionImage()` in your `Update()`; they're not going to do anything there.

Comment: @Foggzie okay, getting rid of it.

Comment: How can I get the size of the Recttransform

Comment: `var rectTransform = imageReference.GetComponent<RectTransform>();` then `rectTransform.rect.width`

Comment: That'll also return the _local_ width so you have to be aware of any scale differences in parent objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the position of the image, whereas you should be translating it.

For example, if your image's X position gets set to 100 every time it goes below -100, you will lose however far below -100 it went.
If it gets to -100.02, then when you set it to 100, you will create a gap of 0.02.

Instead, translate it by the width of the image:
transform.Translate(200,0,0) in the example I just gave, which would put it at 99.98 instead of 100, and negate the create of the gap.

Comment: The best result, revelation!

Comment: My workaround was creating a raw image from the canvas and passed the image as a texture , increasing the UV rect x by a scroll speed

Comment: Also i set the texture as repeat rather than clamp